# Java setting variables in subclasses

Tags: java, maven, class

I have a Java project (let's call it Project A) that consists of a class and its subclass. I packaged this project into a .jar file, which I included as a Maven dependency in another project (let's call it Project B).

My subclass in Project A contained a variable as such:

```
int foo = null;
```

And I wanted to perform the following in Project B:

```
Subclass.foo = 3;
```

However, Java kept throwing me a java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError whenever I tried to do this, which it said was caused by a null pointer error.

The minute I moved this variable to the base class in Project A though, it worked. I was able to set the value of foo in Project B.

I have no idea why this worked, would someone who knows about Java be willing to explain this to me?

Comment: Please create a [mcve], else we can only guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because there is no static variable `foo` on `Subclass`. You can only use static variables with the class name like this. To use non-static variables, you have to instantiate the class with the `new` keyword.

Try one of the following:

#### Option #1:

Class 1:

```
public static int foo = null;
```

Class 2:

```
Subclass foo = 3;
```

#### Option #2:

Class 1:

```
public int foo = null;
```

Class 2:

```
Subclass subclass = new Subclass();
subclass.foo = 3;
```

Also, note that I added the `public` modifier. By default, the variable is only available to others in the same package. Given you have two different projects, I don't think that's the case here.

---

Edit:

Someone ([Lino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5515060/lino)) reminded me in the comments that int can't be `null`. Either replace `int` with `Integer`, or `null` with `0`.

Comment: `int` can't be `null`, OP probably meant `Integer`

Comment: Ah yeah, overlooked that one.